# why i can't access the webserver inside vagrant via my web browser?

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtualbox

I created a vagrant environment where there is 2 VM's in the private network , i need this because i want them to be able to communicate with each other like application server and database server.So here is my vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.define "mac1" do |mac1|
 mac1.vm.box = "kaorimatz/centos-6.8-x86_64"

 mac1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.101"
 mac1.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
end

config.vm.define "mac2" do |mac2|
  mac2.vm.box = "fully-functional"

  mac2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.102"
  mac2.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8081
  mac2.vm.synced_folder "./piwik", "/var/www/html"
end
end
```

now lets say i want to reach only mac2 VM via browser.but i am putting the url like *http://localhost:8081* but it says site is not reachable.In that machine when i run the command *ifconfig* here is the result:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:AF:D5:5C  
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feaf:d55c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2779 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1504 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:221177 (215.9 KiB)  TX bytes:165269 (161.3 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4E:48:A7  
      inet addr:192.168.56.102  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe4e:48a7/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1114 (1.0 KiB)  TX bytes:2408 (2.3 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

I also added that lines to apache conf :

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mac2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 </VirtualHost>
```

And i can also listen to the port 8081 like *telnet localhost 8081*

but i couldnt reach the webserver by any means however i can try.Pls help thank you in advance.

Comment: Your host and `mac2` have the same IP address.

Comment: sorry , i coundt get that ,how ?

Comment: Should be possible via port forwarding (in Vagrantfile: `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567`). Documentation: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vagrant/getting-started-networking

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing with two vagrant instances using the "kaorimatz/centos-6.8-x86_64" box (even after being fully updated during provisioning):

When I used a different box, I was then able to forward ports. The only change I made was with the **Vagrantfile config.vm.box** value. I suspect it's a "kaorimatz/centos-6.8-x86_64" issue but I'm not going to investigate the kaorimatz box as the alternative box worked.

(I used the "bmcgonigle/centos68" box.)

```
#config.vm.box = "kaorimatz/centos-6.8-x86_64"
config.vm.box = "bmcgonigle/centos68"
```

I had tried the same thing with the private network but had no success with it. I got suspicious of the kaorimatz box when I noticed that I had other vagrant dev configs that forwarded ports with no issues. Best of luck!

Comment: for me and t might be in your case was the system's firewall.After i rearrange the firewall setting it is solved

Comment: You are probably right. It was just quicker for me to change the box than reconfigure the firewall every time I made a change to the box.